# How to get app directory in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.6.7.
I can get webroot folder's file by cakephp as follows:

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>assets/frontend/layout/scripts/layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here `$this->webroot;` return the path till webroot. but if i want to get the path of till app how to do this?. i.e: I want to to get a file located at:
app/Vendor/ajaxLiveSearch/js/ajaxlivesearch.js

I tried as follows:

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->app; ?>Vendor/ajaxLiveSearch/js/ajaxlivesearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here what I wanted is: get the path till app folder by $this->app. but it is not right way.How can I do this?

Comment: You should be accessing files like this as they’re outside the webroot.

Answer (score 0):

To access the app directory you can use cakephp defined constant `APP_DIR`
For your case this should be

```
<script src="<?php echo APP; ?>Vendor/ajaxLiveSearch/js/ajaxlivesearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Please check and let me know any issues

Comment: [how APP is defined](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.x/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php#L53) - This answer will output `<script src="/var/www/app/Vendor/ajaxLiveSearch/js/ajaxlivesearch.js">` - it's still as wrong as before, this is simply not the right way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

### Use helpers

Helpers should always be used to link to files, not constants. Using the helpers ensures the right path irrespective of how the application is installed. E.g. using [HtmlHelper::script](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::script), with an app installed in a subfolder:

```
echo $this->Html->script('/assets/frontend/layout/scripts/layout.js');
```

will output:

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="/subfolder/assets/frontend/layout/scripts/layout.js"></script>
```

If the application is installed in the root, the `/subfolder` prefix will be omitted, and the path will still be correct.

### Only the webroot folder is accessible

> I want to to get a file located at: app/Vendor/ajaxLiveSearch/js/ajaxlivesearch.js

This simply will not work. The [default rewrite rules](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.7/.htaccess) only allow access to the webroot folder; this is by design as is prevents unexpected behavior or exploits by short-circuiting the framework and directly accessing files that are expected by the application to be private.

To access a file that is not in the webroot, *move or copy it* to the webroot so that it *is* accessible.

e.g.:

```
cd /my/app/webroot
ln -s ../Vendor/ajaxLiveSearch ajaxLiveSearch
```

Be very careful doing this to not make files accessible that you don't want.